Building with Experience Builder
Brand new at this, so please go easy on me.
I'm building a site with the Experience Builder in Salesforce and I've downloaded and installed the Flexi-Grid Layout module to create multi-column layouts, but I'm not able to drag anything into that container? Am I missing something? I've created an HTML element that I want repeated in three columns, but I've tried dragging on the screen and within the Page Structure table, all to no avail. Help?
